# Why is ng-show not showing or hiding my element based on the expression?

Tags: angularjs

I have:

```
<span class="inlineBlock fa fa-question-circle"
      ng-show="!(validateEmail(ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail)=='OK')"
      title="{{ validateEmail(ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail) }}">{{ validateEmail(ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail) }}</span>
```

The value of validateEmail is set with the following:

```
    $scope.validateEmail = function (error) {
        if (error.$error) {
            if (error.$error.required) return "Required";
            if (error.$error.email) return "Email Invalid";
        } 
        return "OK";
    }
```

But even when it returns OK then the show is still showing the fa-question-circle icon with the word OK next to it. Note that I have tried several different combinations of parenthesis and I always see either the words Required, Email Invalid or OK.  I never see the word not showing.

Comment: ng-show="validateEmail(ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail)!='OK'"

Comment: I think there is more to this. I updated the question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: It's impossible to check your code 'cause you choose to submit an example that we can't use "as is" to reproduce the issue. Here's a working http://jsfiddle.net/fmtj0cpf/ for you, with simplified code.

Comment: Here's another one, updated to more closely emulate what your doing: http://jsfiddle.net/fmtj0cpf/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine "as is" if `ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail` is what it should be, but fails if it is not, and here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmtj0cpf/2/) to prove it.

I copy/pasted your code and just added the required objects that you left out from your question.

Did you check the console for errors? Angular gets very upset if for example `ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail` should happen to be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

my only guess is the `inlineBlock` class is overriding the `display` CSS property, does it still happen after you remove that class?

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what is happening. You should pass the input to the validateEmail function in order to check if it contains a valid value. So, try this:

```
<form name="form" >
    <input type="email" name="emailField" ng-model="ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail"/>
    <span class="inlineBlock fa fa-question-circle" ng-show="validateEmail(form.emailField) != 'OK'"></span>
</form>
```